# Getting data from warcraft logs API using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets

I'm new to javascript and trying to get the parses for this character from warcraft logs into a spreadsheet on google sheets. So far I have this but it keeps logging Null value.

```js
function test() {
  

  var response =
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/parses/character/Fistweaverz/Illidan/US? 
  api_key=xxxxx");

  
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(data["percentile"]);
}
```

the log for the object "data":

```
 [20-06-18 15:21:40:946 EDT] Logging output too large. Truncating
 output. [{estimated=true, rank=236.0, duration=185352.0,
 difficulty=5.0, total=88467.5, percentile=94.8197862291822,
 talents=[{id=196607.0, name=Eye of the Tiger,
 icon=ability_druid_primalprecision.jpg}, {id=116841.0,
 icon=ability_monk_tigerslust.jpg, name=Tiger's Lust}, {name=Fist of
 the White Tiger, id=261947.0, icon=inv_fistofthewhitetiger.jpg},
 {id=116844.0, icon=spell_monk_ringofpeace.jpg, name=Ring of Peace},
 {name=Inner Strength, icon=ability_monk_domeofmist.jpg, id=261767.0},
 {name=Hit Combo, icon=ability_monk_palmstrike.jpg, id=196740.0},
 {name=Whirling Dragon Punch, icon=ability_monk_hurricanestrike.jpg,
 id=152175.0}],
 corruption={activePowers=[{icon=inv_wand_1h_nzothraid_d_01.jpg,
 name=Ineffable Truth, id=318303.0, corruption=12.0}, {name=Lash of the
 Void, corruption=25.0, id=317290.0,
 icon=spell_priest_voidtendrils.jpg}, {corruption=25.0, name=Lash of
 the Void, id=317290.0, icon=spell_priest_voidtendrils.jpg}],
 passivePowers=[{name=Versatile, corruption=20.0, id=315553.0,
 icon=spell_arcane_arcanetactics.jpg}, {name=Versatile, id=315553.0,
 icon=spell_arcane_arcanetactics.jpg, corruption=20.0},
 {corruption=10.0, icon=spell_arcane_arcanetactics.jpg, name=Versatile,
 id=315549.0}, {id=315553.0, name=Versatile,
 icon=spell_arcane_arcanetactics.jpg, corruption=20.0},
 {name=Versatile, corruption=20.0, id=315553.0, icon=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrapped in an array, here is how you access it: `data[0]['percentile'];`

If it was just a normal JSON object, your implementation would be correct. Since it is not and has been wrapped in an array (JSON.parse() does this), you will need to specify the location in the array prior to accessing the values. Hope this helps!